# Uniqueness vs. Unicity

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, synonyms

*Uniqueness* and *unicity* can be synonyms when they are used to describe something that is “unique”, meaning something that is distinct from all other things.

Are these terms interchangeable, or do they carry slightly different meanings?

Comment: I suspect most people would take "Unicity" to be a town where everyone rides unicycles.

Comment: You'll sound unique if you say *unicity*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Mathematicians' answer**

Mathematicians (whose native language is not English) may use *unicity*, modeled after the French *unicité*, in place of the preferable word *uniqueness*.

In a similar way, foreign mathematicians also use *compacity* in place of *compactness*.  Even if the mathematician is a native speaker of English, if his *teacher* was foreign, he may still have picked up *compacity* and *unicity*.

Another one is *analiticity*.  But there is no (common) English word *analiticness*, so in this case I guess there is no avoiding *analiticity*.

Comment: (Upvoted.) Note, though, that this does not mean that mathematicians in general will understand what meaning you intent to convey when using *unicity*. In my (non-native English and non-native French) circle *unicity* will not be ring any bell. I'd even argue it's worse to use it in a mathematical context as keywords like "uniqueness" are used in a very codified manner and it's thus more confusing than the use in a non-specialized text.

Comment: @Perseids "Unicity" is common enough in math that the MathWorld article *Uniqueness Theorem* begins "A theorem, also called a unicity theorem […]." It's still less common, but it's a competitive usage rather than being completely out of left field. I think GEdgar's answer captures that properly.

Comment: independency vs independence too?

Comment: Also worth mentioning (the perhaps obvious) fact that France is a mathematics powerhouse.

Answer (score 13):

All three of *uniqueness, uniquity,* and *unicity* are attested by the Oxford English Dictionary, each with several centuries of citations.  There is no especial difference in meaning between them; there is, however, a [staggering difference in frequency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uniqueness%2Cunicity%2Cuniquity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuniqueness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunicity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuniquity%3B%2Cc0).

Here’s what you should therefore do:

- Use *uniquity* only when you wish to rhyme with such words as *iniquity*, or when you wish to express the antonym of *ubiquity* using a form closely parallel to that word.
- Use *unicity* only when you wish to rhyme with such words as *complicity*, or when you wish to express the antonym of *multi-city.* ¹
- **Use *uniqueness* everywhere else.**

If you don’t use *uniqueness*, you are apt to perplex readers for one of two reasons:

1. Some because they have limited vocabularies or imaginations and so waste time thinking you used an unknown word just because they didn’t know what it means and weren’t in the mood for looking it up.
2. Others because their vocabularies are broad enough that they recognize the synonym but instead waste time wondering why you have chosen a rare word instead of its workaday synonym.

What it all comes down to is that *uniqueness* is the only one in common use, as shown by [this Google N-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uniqueness%2Cunicity%2Cuniquity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuniqueness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunicity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuniquity%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Ngram of uniqueness, unicity, and uniquity]

<sup>**Click graph to go directly to full Ngram.**</sup>

That means that *uniquity* and *unicity* are “special-effects” words only, with *uniqueness* doing all the real work to express **“one-of-a-kindness”** in the language.

---

#### Footnotes

1. Which does not in the second instance rhyme with *complicity*, since when opposing *multicity*, *unicity* has two stresses not one.

   > “We need a multicity solution to our traffic problems during rush hour. A unicity approach just won’t work.”

Comment: I find this answer a bit confusing --is it ever acceptable to use a word just for the sake of a rhyme?  Even if you're writing rhymed poetry, you would typically want to stick to words that are otherwise legitimate.  Or is that part of the answer a joke?

Comment: @ChrisSunami All three words can be found in the OED. That doesn’t make them equally applicable.

Comment: Two stresses? so it'll rhyme with 'more than one city'?

Comment: Of course poets (who do rhyming poetry, nowadays a small minority) choose unusual words for the purpose of rhyming.  Even Shakespeare did this on occasion.

Comment: @tchrist I get that, and I thought the definitions were great, but the advice for usage seemed odd.  After all, *any* word can be used for the sake of a rhyme (except, I guess, *orange*, *etc.*).  To suggest that as the main reason for using a word is worse than damning with faint praise.

Comment: @ChrisSunami I believe I have been clear, and fail to understand your beef.

Comment: 'To suggest that as the main reason for using a word is worse than damning with faint praise.' Exactly.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Apparently subtlety is subappreciated here. I could have easily written a mind-numbingly simple-minded one-liner answer hidden in a comment that blunderbusses people with Prescriptivist Commandment CCLIV (**“Thou shalt uniquely use *uniqueness* and stop asking questions.”**) , which would have set the GR close-voters upon this question. Is that what the Community desires?

Comment: @ChrisSunami I'm not sure what you don't understand here. tchrist says that the words are attested (and thus valid descriptively and prescriptively). Then he recommends that you don't use them because they are very rare and many people will take exception to your use of them. Then he suggests a usage (poetry) where they will actually fit very well and nobody could possibly object. What's confusing or unclear here?

Comment: I'm surprised Gilbert and Sullivan didn't write a song using them all in the same verse.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Since I'm the only person bothered, I'll drop it.  It just seemed odd to me to single out as a reason for using a word something that could literally be said of nearly any other word ("Is this beef any good?"  "Well, you can eat it.")  Given that, I was inquiring if it was just a joking way of saying "don't use this word!" --which seems in fact to be the case.

Comment: Like GEdgar says, there's the Math context "Prove the unicity of the solution"

Comment: @ChrisSunami: tchrist was trying to avoid saying "don't use this word" when the word can in fact be reasonably used (in poetry).  The same is not true of (e.g.) quethe, since that's too obscure even for poetic senses (except in past tense *quoth*).

Answer (score 2):

There are dictionaries which register more or less all words, whether they are 
"dictionary corpses" or not. The Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English has only unique and uniqueness, neither unicity nor uniquity. By the way, also the smaller
Concise Oxford Dictionary has only uniqueness. I should say unicity and uniquity are dictionary corpses a journalist may dig out and revive to sweep his readers of their feet with his exquisite vocabulary or a poet may use these corpses when he is in need of a special rhyme.

PS I refer to my edition of The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Current English in bookform, 9th edition, 1995.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unicity

Comment: @crl - oxforddictionaries.com should habe a note about the frequency of unicity. The British National Corpus has only one single instance for this word. For "uniqueness" there are 238. And for uniquity none.